# Inactive JDIalog in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I made two JDialogs, one with usage of Intellij GUI editor and one not. When I try to open `ChooseEmailAccountDialog` it appears active, but than it somehow deactivate and hide under InboxMain `JDialog`. I will be glad for any help, I have no idea how to solve this.

**ChooseEmailAccountDialog**:

```
public class ChooseEmailAccountDialog extends JDialog
{
    //Array list of user defined email accounts
    private ArrayList<EmailAccount> emailAccountArrayList;
    private JPanel jPanel1;
    public ChooseEmailAccountDialog(final ArrayList<EmailAccount> emailAccountArrayList)
    {
        this.emailAccountArrayList = emailAccountArrayList;
        setTitle("Choose email account");
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        double width = screenSize.getWidth();
        double height = screenSize.getHeight();
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(300,200);
        this.setMinimumSize(dim);
        this.setPreferredSize(dim);
        this.setLocation(new Point((int) width / 2 - this.getWidth() / 2, (int) height / 2 - this.getHeight() / 2));
        jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(emailAccountArrayList.size(),1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(gridLayout);
        //Adding texts on a buttons
        ArrayList<JButton> jButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        for(EmailAccount x: emailAccountArrayList)
        {
            JButton temp = new JButton(x.getEmailAddress());
            temp.addActionListener(new ActionListenerNewMessageButton(temp.getText(),emailAccountArrayList));
            jButtons.add(temp);
        }
        for(JButton x : jButtons)
        {
            jPanel1.add(x);
        }
        this.getContentPane().add(jPanel1);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
       ;
    }

}
```

And InboxMain `JDialog` (created with Intellij GUI Editor):

```
public class InboxMain extends JDialog
{
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable messagesJTable;
    private JButton newEmailButton;
    private JButton refreshInboxButton;
    private JButton buttonOK;
    //All accounts configured by user
    private ArrayList<EmailAccount> emailAccountArrayList;
    public InboxMain(final ArrayList<EmailAccount> emailAccountArrayList)
    {
        this.emailAccountArrayList = emailAccountArrayList;;
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setModal(true);
        getRootPane().setDefaultButton(buttonOK);
        newEmailButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                ChooseEmailAccountDialog chooseEmailAccountDialog = new ChooseEmailAccountDialog(emailAccountArrayList);
                chooseEmailAccountDialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And the gif :
https://gfycat.com/PositiveGrouchyAnnashummingbird

**SOURCE: https://github.com/mmajews/Emailer**

Problem solved. Adding `setModal(true)` line solves the problem.

Comment: Can you post your complete code so that we can debug your code. You can remove the picture to make your post smaller

Comment: @afzalex I edited my post and posted the source :)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Comment: Your code is containing many errors and mistakes apart from the problem you are asking.

Comment: @afzalex Can you provide me Information about mistakes and errors I make ? I will be very glad to learn something new :)